# How can I declare the types for this problem?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a simple programming language with some primitives and user defined functions.

These are the types I created:

```hs
data Type = IntT | BoolT

data Value = IntV Int | BoolV Bool | OperatorCall String [Value]

data Expr = LetE String Value | ProcedureCall String [Value]
```

As you can see, I've divided functions into operators (which return a value) and procedures (which don't return anything and act as expressions instead of values). A function call contains the string id of the function being called and the list of arguments being passed. Also, a program is just a list of expressions (I've omitted user defined functions here for the sake of simplicity)

My problem comes from the fact that I need to write a function that parses a function call from a string:

```hs
parseFunctionCall :: String -> ???
...
```

The return type of that function can be a `Value` (for operator calls) or an `Expr` (for procedure calls). This function is rather complicated and I'd prefer to avoid writing it twice, or polluting it with an `Either` return type. What should I do? How can I change my types so that this can be achieved cleanly? Something like this perhaps, but I don't think this is the way:

```hs
type FunctionCall = (String, [Value])

data Value = ... | OperatorCall FunctionCall

data Expr = ... | ProcedureCall FunctionCall

parseAsFunctionCall :: String -> FunctionCall
...
```

Comment: Why don't you think that's the way?

Comment: What do you dislike about using the `Either` type here?  You call it pollution, but as I see it this is the kind of thing it is designed for.

Comment: Having a constructor that says `OperatorCall FunctionCall` doesn't seem very intuitive to me @DanielWagner . Maybe if I renamed them it would make more sense?

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco Okay. I'll write about how to fix that infelicity.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but the parsing function can fail to parse the string, so instead of `FunctionCall` its return type should be `Maybe FunctionCall`. If I had to add `Either` on top of all that, it would look like `Maybe (Either Value Expr)` and I would have two make two checks every time I used the function @ÉamonnOlive

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco You will almost certainly have to change it even farther than that, to return the part of the `String` that wasn't parsed (e.g. `String -> Maybe (String, Either Value Expr)` or similar). But don't reinvent the wheel unless the goal is learning how this stuff is implemented -- instead use one of the many excellent parser combinator libraries that already exist.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's even more complex. That's why I'm trying to find another way around @DanielWagner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the function call parser return `(String, [Value])`, and let the caller fix that up into whatever data structure they like best -- in your case, by applying `\(s, vs) -> OperatorCall s vs` if parsing a value or `\(s, vs) -> ProcedureCall s vs` if parsing an expression.

```
parseFunctionCall :: Parser (String, [Value])
parseLiteralInt :: Parser Int
parseLiteralBool :: Parser Bool
parseLet :: Parser (String, Value)
(parseFunctionCall, parseLiteralInt, parseBool, parseLet) = {- ... -}

parseValue :: Parser Value
parseValue =
    ((\(s, vs) -> OperatorCall s vs) <$> parseFunctionCall)
    <|>
    (IntV <$> parseLiteralInt)
    <|>
    (BoolV <$> parseLiteralBool)

parseExpr :: Parser Expr
    ((\(s, vs) -> ProcedureCall s vs) <$> parseFunctionCall)
    <|>
    ((\(s, v) -> Let s v) <$> parseLet)
```

Comment: So `parseFunctionCall` actually returns a `FunctionCall`, and then I can convert that to the corresponding type. Thanks!